# Why I got this task email subject: "has been assigned to you again"?

Tags: tasks

I have a workflow which is creating tasks. When creating these tasks I set the title, body, status etc fields. When the workflow start It creates the task and I will receive an email because the task is assigned to me. The subject of the email is very strange:

at emvironment 1 (web application in dutch)
Taken - Test1 is opnieuw aan u toegewezen

I will translate the dutch text for you in englisch: 
Tasks- Test1 has been assigned to you again

at environment 2 (web application in englisch) I got this as subject
Taken - Test2 has been assigned to you

I am looking for the differance why at envirounment 1 got in the subject like the task is assigned again. This is not OK, because the task is new and I receive the email for the first time.

Can someone tell me more about when you get an email from the task with the subject "has been assigned to you again" ??

Comment: It could be a language pack issue. Google translate says that is "re-assigned to you" which still isn't right. It seems like it might be a bug in the localization of the language pack.

Comment: but, is there also a task mail subject with the word reassigned? If the answer is yes, when someone gets this task mail subject?

Comment: I think it is a bug in SharePoint. The language pack like PirateEric says. Can I create my own custom subject in c# code?